# Cordova import:SDK build tool revision is too low for project in android studio

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I am trying to import cordova project into android studio.But i will get the following  error while gradle build.

> Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.0) is too low for project
>   ':..:..:..:..:Root5projects:KTDC:platforms:android'. Minimum required
>   is 19.1.0

**build.gradle**  in the project folder

```
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
```

**CordovaLib\build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

I have referred many question but nothing works for me.

Cordova version is 4.0.0

android studio version 1.2.2

Also installed the SDK build tools `19.1,21.1.2,22.0.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.Actually that is the problem of Cordova version,I have updated my Cordova now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do phonegap/cordova project using Android Studio. Use eclipse instead Android Studio.